# jQuery - hover to show sidebar, but an option to lock it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, addclass

I have a side bar which when you mouseover it slides over the content, when you mouseout it slides back. All working great.

I then have a button which when you click it, it locks the sidebar in place, pushing the content behind over. Locking the sidebar in place. Also works great..

My problem is that I wish for when the sidebar to be locked, to disable the hover, and keep it in the expanded state, then when you unlock it, to go back and re-enable hovering.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VW5Hg/19/)

Thanks

```
$('.sec-sidebar-toggle').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).closest('.sec-sidebar').hasClass('sidebar-locked')) {
        //unlocked
        $(this).closest('.sec-sidebar').removeClass('sidebar-locked');
        $(this).closest('.sec-sidebar').stop().animate({
            width: '38px'
        }, 300).css({
            'overflow': 'visible'
        });
    } else {
        //locked
        $(this).closest('.sec-sidebar').addClass('sidebar-locked');
        $(this).closest('.sec-sidebar').stop().animate({
            width: '253px'
        }, 300).css({
            'overflow': 'visible'
        });
    }
});

//Hover
$('.sec-sidebar').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).find('.sec-nav').stop().animate({
        marginLeft: '0px'
    }, 300);
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).find('.sec-nav').stop().animate({
        marginLeft: '-215px'
    }, 300);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unbind the mouseover and mouseout events.

http://jsfiddle.net/3n1gm4/VEUe9/

```
$('.sec-sidebar-toggle').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if( $(this).closest('.sec-sidebar').hasClass('sidebar-locked') ){
    //unlocked
    $(this).closest('.sec-sidebar').removeClass('sidebar-locked');
    $(this).closest('.sec-sidebar').stop().animate({width: '38px'}, 300).css({'overflow': 'visible'});

    // ADD EVENT HANDLERS
    setupHover();
  } else{
    //locked
    $(this).closest('.sec-sidebar').addClass('sidebar-locked');
    $(this).closest('.sec-sidebar').stop().animate({width: '253px'}, 300).css({'overflow': 'visible'});

    // REMOVE EVENT HANDLERS
    $('.sec-sidebar').unbind('mouseover');
    $('.sec-sidebar').unbind('mouseout');
  }
});

function setupHover() {

    //Hover
    $('.sec-sidebar').mouseover(function(){
      $(this).find('.sec-nav').stop().animate({marginLeft: '0px'}, 300);
    }).mouseout(function(){
      $(this).find('.sec-nav').stop().animate({marginLeft: '-215px'}, 300);
    });
}

setupHover();
```

Comment: Also, for the other posters. I know this is what you all said (very grateful) but the reason I chose b.kelley as correct answer is because he actually wrote it out and I'm very new to jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I have wrapped the mouseout function in an IF statement to check whether the sidebar has the `sidebar-locked` class. If it does the following animation will not be executed.

```
if(!$('.sec-sidebar').hasClass('sidebar-locked')){
  $(this).find('.sec-nav').stop().animate({marginLeft: '-215px'}, 300);
}
```

Is this what you were hoping to achieve?

Here is the [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gjYkQ/).

Note: The `!` at the start of the IF statement is to say IF NOT. So, If not this class in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

There are two easy solutions in my head.

1: You could check the classes of the sidebar if 'sidebar-locked' is present with .hasClass() in the mouseevents.

2: You could remove the mouse events completely by unbinding them when you lock it and rebinding them when you unlock it.
See [jQuery API: unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/).

Sidenote:
Consider using the [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event instead of the two seperate mouse events.

Comment: Yeah, i was already preparing the post and noticed it too late. At least we agree

Comment: I figured, just quite the coincidence.  Too many times have I posted an answer that was posted 2 secs before lol. apparently this is what happened :(.  Jamie posted, you posted, then I posted lol

Answer (score 0):

You should to clear mouseover event handler, and reassign it back when it needs.
[Remove an event handler](http://api.jquery.com/off/).